# Whats the difference between HttpClient.Timeout and using the WebRequestHandler timeout properties?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I can set the timeout of my `HttpClient` object directly with `HttpClient.Timeout` but I've recently read about the `WebRequestHandler` class which is a derivative of `HttpClientHandler`.

`WebRequestHandler` has a `ReadWriteTimeout` property.  How will this affect the operation of the request when used alongside `HttpClient.Timeout`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you perform a `SendAsync` the `HttpClient.Timeout` is placed on the `CancellationTokenSource`. This means this timeout is for the entire async operation.

On the other hand, `WebRequestHandler.ReadWriteTimeout` is copied to the `HttpWebRequest` where it is set on the request stream both `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout`. So this is more a timeout at the stream level, which is ultimately a socket level timeout.

If you set both, then if the operation takes more than `HttpClient.Timeout` in total it will timeout, and if a read or write from the stream takes longer than `WebRequestHandler.ReadWriteTimeout` it will also timeout. Though I am not sure if there is a difference in the timeout exceptions raised.

Comment: Since it's related to streams, would `ReadWriteTimeout` affect `Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync` then?   At the moment I use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead` when calling `SendAsync` to make sure the content is read before the timeout, because `ReadAsStringAsync` doesn't allow an explicit timeout or cancellation.  I'd like to use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` instead, if `WebRequestHandler` allows me to set a timeout on reading the content stream.

Comment: It's a bit hard to picture your use case from the description, can you post the relevant code by editing the question?

Answer (score 1):

`WebRequestHandler.ReadWriteTimeout` - Gets or sets a time-out in milliseconds when writing a request to or reading a response from a server.

`HttpClient.Timeout` - Gets or sets the `TimeSpan` to wait before the request times out.

Here, `WebRequestHandler` is a wrapper over `HTTPClient`
`WebRequestHandler` derives from `HttpClientHandler` but adds properties that generally only are available on full .NET. 
To conclude, it is more on less same thing.

For more info refer this link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-httpwebrequesthandler.aspx