# HttpClient timing out before specified timeout sometimes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have an ASP.NET Web API `Z` that is calling two services, `A` and `B`.

The client calling `Z` will timeout after 500ms. I have dedicated 150ms to getting a response from `A` before timing out, and 300ms to `B` before timing out. The timeout for both of these `HttpClient`s is set using the `Timeout` property.

When the timeout for `B` is set to 300ms, I do not get a response in 300ms. I get a `TaskCancelledException`.

However, when I set the timeout for `B` to 1 second, I get an end-to-end response of ~180-240ms, less than the timeout for `B` itself.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = baseAddress,
    Timeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00.300");
};

using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(_endpoint, content))
{
    // ...
}
```

Exception:

```
System.Net.WebException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Additional information: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
```

Is there something that I"m doing wrong? Can someone explain this strange behavior?

Comment: Could it be that timeouts and timers in general is not that precise?

Comment: Also see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313172/whats-the-difference-between-httpclient-timeout-and-using-the-webrequesthandler